# Loop over to create new variables from uniform dataframe

Tags: r, random, tidyverse, simulation, uniform

My problem is the following

I want to create variables e_1, e_2, e_3, ... , e_50 which are all composed of 100 draws from the uniform[-1,1]

This means e_1 is a vector of 100 draws from U[-1.1], e_2, .., e_50 as well.

Here is what I thought I could do :

```
periods <- c(1:50)
people <- c(1:100)
for (t in periods){
sprint('e_', t) <- runif(100, -1,1)
}
```

This did not work, and i am really not sure how to change it to obtain what I want.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better not to create objects in the global environment.  Regarding the issue in the code, the assignment should be based on `assign`

```
for(t in periods) {
    assign(sprintf('e_%d', t), runif(100, -1, 1))
}
```

---

An approach that wouldn't create multiple objects in the global env, would be to create a `list` with `replicate`

```
lst1 <- replicate(length(periods), runif(100, -1, 1), simplify = FALSE)
names(lst1) <- sprintf('e_%d', periods)
```

Comment: Hi Akrun! It does not really work, when i run your for loop, I only get in. my global environment a single variable which is 'e_' .

Ok for your second approach, but how do i 1. Call each element of the list e_1, e_2 ... and then how do i put them in my dataframe as columns?

Comment: @Lola1993 sorry, I didn't check your `sprintf` command.  Updated.  It should be `'e_%d'` as `t` is numeric

Comment: Ahhh ok !!! Thank you so much! But i actually really like your advice of not saving everything in global environment, I think that is much better.

Comment: Would you have any way to name all the elements of the list by having a sprint f or something?

Comment: @Lola1993 Regarding the second option with `list`,  you can loop over the `list` with `lapply` if you want to do some operations i.e. `lapply(lst1, yourfun)`

Comment: Updated.  `sprintf` is vectorized.  So you can do as `names(lst1) <- sprintf('e_%d', periods)` or with `paste0` ie. `paste0('e_', periods)`